# Why some objects are not rendered in the final rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects, 3d-view

So this is how it looks when I get a preview rendering in the 3D viewport:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGkPr.jpg

This is how it looks when I press render for a final result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQCF3.jpg

I have no idea what's happening. Can someone help me figure the problem out?

Comment: Include images inline into the question body please, see how https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I have to go to the *OBJECT MODE* -> <kbd>W</kbd> -> Clear

Objects can be set to 'Restrict Render' - effectively to exclude them from the render (the camera icon in the Outliner window). The <kbd>W</kbd> shortcut brings up a Specials menu with 'Restrict Render Unselected' and 'Clear All Restrict Render' options - the first option sets all objects except those currently selected to be hidden, while the second option sets everything back to render.

Comment: Yeah I pressed the first option accidentally at some moment